# Name of emulator I'm using?

Tags: android

I'm developing a project in Android. I know every emulator has some specific name like Gameboid,Frodo, Gearoid etc. How can I get to know the name of Emulator on which i am working??

Comment: can you explain in details exact what you want ?

Comment: I m developing a project in android for my college project. I know that every emulator has a specific name but I dnt know about my emulator name.So i want to know the name of emulator on which m working.How can I know that?

Comment: @ChiragRaval- If u still need more xplanation den tell me....

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

emulator -avd System -version

I recommend to read more from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping)!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse :

Open `Android Virtual Device Manager` and check the `Platform` of your AVD(Android virtual device).

Programmatically :

```
String sdkVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK;
```

Comment: ... although, on second look... it doesn't get you the version of the emulator, but rather the version of Android running on the emulator...

Comment: @ClassStacker- I think u r rite..I shuld use d word 'name' of emulator instead of its version bcoz every emulator has its specific name.So nw cn u answer my question?